# I'm having trouble plotting a 2D graph alongside a 3D graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code block that produces a 3d graph

```
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.plot3D(outputs_real, outputs_imaginary, inputs)
ax.set_xlabel('Real Component')
ax.set_ylabel('Imaginary Component')
ax.set_zlabel('Inputs')
plt.show()
```

[image]
and a second code block that makes a 2d graph using 2 of the above's axes.

```
ax2 = plt.plot(outputs_real, outputs_imaginary)
ax2.set_xlabel('Real Component')
ax2.set_ylabel('Imaginary Component')
```

But for some reason when I try to plot the second one I'll get this error

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'`

and the second graph will map onto the first like this:
[image]

I want the two graphs to be separate

Details:

1. This is being done in a Jupyter notebook
2. outputs_real, outputs_imaginary, and inputs are all lists

Comment: `ax2 = plt.plot(...)` is never correct.  If you want to create subplots, you need something like [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/mixed_subplots.html)

Comment: See also [How to scale 3D and 2D subplots so that a corresponding axis has the same length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154633/how-to-scale-3d-and-2d-subplots-so-that-a-corresponding-axis-has-the-same-length) and [remove 3D plot's white spaces in mixed 2D/3D subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917886/matplotlib-remove-3d-plots-white-spaces-in-mixed-2d-3d-subplots)

Answer (score 0):

From matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) `plt.plot` returns a list of lines representing the plotted data.

If you want to change the x and y label use `plt.xlabel('text')` and `plt.ylabel('text')` as following:

```
plt.plot(outputs_real, outputs_imaginary)
plt.xlabel('Real Component')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary Component')
```

An example to create a 2D and 3D separate graphs:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# create 3d data
z = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
x = np.sin(z)
y = np.cos(z)

# plot 3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(x, y, z)
ax.set_title("3D plot")
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.show()

# plot 2D
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("2D plot")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

This will create the following two plots:

[image: 3D]

[image: 2D]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a new figure. After you have called the first `plt.show()` create a new figure and ax with

```
plt.figure(2)
ax2 = plt.axes()
```

You can also plot the two figures simultaneously if you want, by not calling the first `plt.show()` and only calling `plt.show()` after creating both of the figures.