# Way to specify viewpoint distance in 3d plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection, matplotlib-3d

I am working on an animation of a 3D plot using mpl_toolkits.mplot3d (Matplotlib 3.6.3) and need to set the view distance.

It seems that earlier versions of Matplotlib allowed the elevation, azimuth, and distance of the viewpoint "camera" to be set for 3D plots using methods like this:

```
ax.elev = 45
ax.azim = 10
ax.dist = 2
```

but the distance attribute appears to have been deprecated for some reason:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
    ax.dist = 2
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The dist attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.
```

This still runs, but the output plots have all sorts of visual artifacts that only go away if I shut off the axes with ax.set_axis_off().

Is there an equivalent means of setting the viewpoint distance to zoom in on a 3D data set in 3.6.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html#axes3d-dist), you now need to use the `zoom` argument of [`set_box_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect):

`ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=2)`

Where the first argument is the aspect ratio. Use `None` to use the default values.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. I was also going to ask how to set the box aspect. The documentation for the aspect ratio says it is float, but it must be a vector e.g. aspect_ratio = (1,1,1) sets the axes equal in 3D.

Comment: For some reason the `zoom` parameter is not [documented](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html).