# Trim white space in a 3D pdf plot (savefig), when bbox_inches='tight' and pad_inches do not have the desired effect

Tags: python, matplotlib, trim, bounding-box, removing-whitespace

With the code below, I have produced a figure which I would like to save it in pdf. I use `savefig` command:

```
fig.savefig("Surface_I.pdf" )
```

The pdf file contains a lot of white space in `left`, and `up`:

[image]

`fig.savefig("Surface_I.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')` solution cuts out a bit of  `x` and `z` information, without removing too much space from `left` and `top`:

[image]

The `fig.savefig("Surface_I.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.3)` solution adds some space, fixing the info just removed:

[image]

but there is still too much space in `left` and `top`.

How could I remove, or trim, all this `left` and `top` white space from the pdf?

Note: all these pictures are a screenshot of the pdf generated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function:
z_fit = a0 + a1*yy + a2*xx + a3*yy**2 + a4*xx**2  + a5*xx*yy

# Parameters:
a0 =  -941.487789948
a1 =  0.0146881652963
a2 =  -2.53533353374e-05
a3 =  -9.64343252786e-05
a4 =  -2.47416662598e-08
a5 =  3.77136886946e-07

x_mesh = np.linspace(10.0000000000000, 2000.0000000000000, 20)
y_mesh = np.linspace(-4.4119598462100, 10.8557347078000, 20)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)


# Plot the function
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_fit, color='b', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('\nx')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('\nzzzzz zzz', linespacing=3)
ax.set_title('\n\nSurface I', linespacing=3)
xlabels=[0, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=90,
                  verticalalignment='baseline',#)#,
                  horizontalalignment='left')

ylabels = [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels,rotation=0,
                  verticalalignment='baseline')#,
#                 horizontalalignment='left')


fig.savefig("Surface_I.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.3)
```

Comment: I think what you want is to set your own bounding box as shown in the answer by tom in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225293/remove-white-spaces-in-axes3d-matplotlib). Possibly it's even enough to adjust the subplot parameters like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604100/matplotlib-3d-plot-how-to-get-rid-of-the-excessive-white-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I cropped the resulting pdf plot manually like this:

```
pdfcrop --margins '0 0 0 0' input.pdf output.pdf
```

From `pdfcrop` help message:

`--margins "<left> <top> <right> <bottom>"`

If you need to crop many plots you can write a simple bash script to automate the process. This whole solution is a bit ugly but it works.

Comment: Thank you very much this is very useful tool to know!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the list border in the code below (border = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax] in numerical device coordinates ) 
It's a bit tricky you create an axis ax0 of size border list
and inside you add the axis for the 3d figure. 
try with border = [-0.5,0,1.5,1] you'll understand the role of this list

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters:
a0 =  -941.487789948
a1 =  0.0146881652963
a2 =  -2.53533353374e-05
a3 =  -9.64343252786e-05
a4 =  -2.47416662598e-08
a5 =  3.77136886946e-07

x_mesh = np.linspace(10.0000000000000, 2000.0000000000000, 20)
y_mesh = np.linspace(-4.4119598462100, 10.8557347078000, 20)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)

# Function:
z_fit = a0 + a1*yy + a2*xx + a3*yy**2 + a4*xx**2  + a5*xx*yy


def axesborder(border):
    # border  = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax] 
    # return [xmin,ymin,dx,dy]
    return [border[0],border[1],border[2]-border[0],border[3]-border[1]]

# Plot the function
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.set_size_inches((16,9), forward=True)
border = [-0.1,0,1.05,1]
#border = [0,0,1,1]
ax0 = fig.add_axes(axesborder(border))
ax0.set_axis_off()

ax = fig.add_axes(ax0.get_position(),projection='3d',zorder = 1)

ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_fit, color='b', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('\nx')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('\nzzzzz zzz', linespacing=3)
ax.set_title('\n\nSurface I', linespacing=3)
xlabels=[0, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=90,
                  verticalalignment='baseline',#)#,
                  horizontalalignment='left')

ylabels = [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels,rotation=0,verticalalignment='baseline')

plt.show()

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```