# Remove excessive top and left margin from matplotlib 3D subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bunch of plots, one is a 3D projection. All the plots look good, except the 3D plot has a ton of empty space above and to the left (see the example). The bottom and right margins look fine, just not the top and left margins. Is there any way to remove this extra white space?

I have tried manually changing the margins but with no apparent effect (they were 0.5, 0.5, 0). The matplotlib rc file has `savefig.bbox = tight`. I tried messing with the position bbox, but that hasn't gone well being a subplot. The problem seems to be related to a 3D plot in a subplot and not alone.

[image]

**EDIT**

[Matplotlib 3d plot: how to get rid of the excessive white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604100/matplotlib-3d-plot-how-to-get-rid-of-the-excessive-white-space) does not answer this question unfortunately, because the 3D plot is not in a sub plot. Changing the left in `subplots_adjust` also damages the non 3D plot. [Remove white spaces in Axes3d (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225293/remove-white-spaces-in-axes3d-matplotlib) also largely requires the same underlying function `subplots_adjust` for the bulk of the adjustment.

Example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')

x_labels = [10,20,30]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,1,5,1]

for label in x_labels:
    x_3d = label * np.ones_like(x)
    ax.plot(x_3d, x, y, color='black')
#
ax.set_zlabel('test')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
ax.plot(time, np.sin(time))

fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=-0.11)  # plot outside the normal area

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
canvas.print_figure(r'D:\test.png')
```

With `tight_layout()` and `subplots_adjust`:
[image]

Without:
[image]